# Find folders and set to variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, directory, extendscript

so I'm having a little trouble here and not sure if its my code or not. I'm trying to select a folder on my computer and then cycle through all interior folders and set them to a variable before I print them out in Javascript

```
    //Manually select folder
var topFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select folder with source files");

var sourceList = new Array();
var sFolder = new Array();
var nFolder = new Array();
var importFolder = new Array();
sFolder = topFolder.getFiles();


mkVar(sFolder);

function mkVar(sFolder)
{
    var innerFolders = [];
    var nFolder = [];
    var mFolder = [];
    var tFolder = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sFolder.length; i++)
    {
        innerFolders[i] = sFolder[i];
        for (var j=0; j<innerFolders.length; j++)
        {
            nFolder[j] = innerFolders[j].getFiles();
            for (var k = 0; k<nFolder.length; k++)
            {
                mFolder[k] = nFolder[k].getFiles();
            }
        }
        
        $.writeln(innerFolders[i]);
        $.writeln(nFolder[i]);
        $.writeln(mFolder[i]);
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run this I get an error that says Function nFolder[k].getFiles is undefined. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `nFolder[k]` may be an ordinary file, not a subfolder. You need to check if it's a folder before trying to get its files.